# Cluster Analysis with Skewed Categorical Data

Tags: r, clustering, skewness

I am working on a cluster analysis and wanted need some clarification on somethings. I have close to a dozen variables. Two of which are categorical variables that have certain observations/levels that occur much more than other observations/levels. For example, Categorical Variable 1 has 3 levels and Level 3 occurs 80% of the time. My question is: Should I include such variables in my cluster analysis?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your data, the algorithm you use,and the objective. There won't be a simple answer.

When 80% are level 3, there is potentially value in the information that some instances are *not* of the majority level.

Why don't you try both, and check which result is more meaningful?

Also consider *weighting*.